# I lost my user password

Tags: boot, password, password-recovery, passwd

Help I have inherited this old computer from my grandfather and I have no clue what the password is and without the password it will not update. does anybody know how to change the user password without the current pass or a way to find the current password?
VER: 16.04 LTS
OS: 64-Bit
If you do have a answer can you make it in simple steps that a noob could understand... Thanks!

Comment: What version and OS?

Comment: 16.04 LTS      64-bit

Comment: I bet your answer would work but i just don't understand what they are saying to do steeldriver :(

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.